# Load a Doctrine persisted entity in async process

Tags: mysql, symfony, asynchronous, doctrine-orm, doctrine

my application creates PDF documents from html code. For that I put the print configuration with doctrine in a mysql database and call a commandline script which calls another symfony controller action with that printjob id.

Now the problem: I got the id right now after persisting the data, but the data isn't in mysql while first process is still running.

How can I tell doctrine, to write the data immediately in the database? I tried already tips like

```
$em->clear()

// or

$em->getConnection()->commit()
```

but I does not help or caused other problems.

Comment: hi Daniel, have you solve? how? thanks for share your experience

Answer (score 0):

try to flush the data with flush like:

`$em->flush()`

You can flush only a single entity:

`$em->flush($object)`

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help. :(

Comment: @Daniel: That seems highly unlikely. Are you targeting the same database server? Do you have some sort of RAM journaling in place?

Comment: @Matteo: clear() disconnects all entities and this causes problems within the first process, because there are more managed entities in relation. commit() raises an error, because there are no transaction.

Comment: @jperovic: Thats happens on my development machine with default ubuntu/mysql installation.

Comment: Just for experimenting purpose can you try setting `sleep(5)` after you write to database? This will delay any subsequent statements for 5 seconds...

Comment: This won't work, because doctrine seems to write the data at the end of process one. sleep() causes a delay, but my async call is still before that. Maybe I am wrong, if I do that generation at this time. I also could trigger it later by a deamon or in the show action. Its more work to do, but maybe more reliable.

Comment: The refresh() I also tried before, without any result.